# Navigation bar stetches layout Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, directx, winrt-xaml

I'm created sample DirectX + XAML C++ application. But navigation bar is stretches layout(with render area) when appearance. How to make navbar over layout?

Answer (score 0):

I set Width/Height properties of SwapChainPanel to screen szies manually. I works, but recuce FPS from 60 to 45-50.

Is there another way?